# Existe alguma diferença significativa em termos de performance ao utilizar o Netbeans com JDK 9, ao invés do JDK 8?

Tags: netbeans, jdk

Existe alguma diferença significativa em termos de performance, que justifique utilizar o Netbeans com JDK 9, ao invés do JDK 8?

Resumidamente, gostaria de saber se o Netbeans apresenta melhor performance (menor consumo de memória, cpu...) com o JDK9 ou se neste ponto a versão 8 se sai melhor?

Comment: PHP com JDK?? Você não se confundiu? PHP não tem nada a ver com JDK, que significa **java development kit**. JDk é pra java, nada ligado a php.

Comment: Pode explicar melhor? Não entendi a relação de uma coisa com a outra...

Comment: Estou votando para fechar esta pergunta como fora de escopo porque virou uma bagunça, além de não clara tem duas respostas completamente distintas e nenhuma responde o que o AP quer (o que parece ser um mistério)

Comment: Depois da edição, a pergunta ficou ainda mais  "sem pé nem cabeça". Concordo com o fechamento.

Answer (score 6):

**Atualização do JDK 9**

Project Jigsaw foi prometido há muito tempo como uma maneira de permitir que programadores escrevessem um código que incluísse módulos independentes. O objetivo da Jigsaw é definir um sistema de módulo padrão para a plataforma Java e usá-lo para modularizar a própria plataforma e aplicações. Jigsaw foi concebido para ser incluído no Java 8, mas perdeu isso, então agora é proposto para o Java 9.

Em uma publicação na lista de discussão OpenJDK, Mark Reinhold, arquiteto-chefe do grupo de plataformas Java da Oracle, disse que a compilação atual implementa todas as mudanças descritas nesse JEP, exceto que o provedor jrt: sistema de arquivos ainda não foi implementado e o mecanismo de extensão ainda não foi removido.

Esses pacotes destinam-se a permitir que os desenvolvedores experimentem o Project Jigsaw sem precisar compilá-lo a partir de fontes. As compilações estão disponíveis [no site do projeto JDK 9](https://jdk9.java.net/).

Também foram feitas mudanças em alguns dos PEC. JEPs, Propostas de aprimoramento de Java, estão sendo usados ​​para permitir que novos recursos sejam discutidos e desenvolvidos sem passar por uma especificação formal completa (JSR). Os PEC que são populares e bem sucedidos serão apresentados como parte da próxima especificação formal completa.

Os JEPs atualizados fornecem registro JVM unificado e mais controles de compilação.

Unified JVM Logging (JEP 158) dará um sistema de log comum para todos os componentes da JVM. Isso mudará a maneira atual pela qual a JVM relata os eventos em seus subsistemas e adicionará opções de linha de comando comuns. Este JEP foi fortemente influenciado pelo que existe no JVM JRockit da Oracle, de acordo com a proposta.

O segundo JEP a ser atualizado, JEP 165, propõe melhorar o controle dos compiladores da JVM encapsulando o controle em um conjunto de opções. Isso permitiria que diferentes conjuntos de opções fossem aplicados dependendo do método que está sendo compilado e abre a possibilidade de alterar os conjuntos de opções durante o tempo de execução.

As sugestões foram feitas como JEPs (Java Enhancement Proposals). Os PECs fornecem um caminho para que novos recursos sejam discutidos e desenvolvidos sem passar por uma especificação formal completa (JSR). A abordagem menos formal torna possível apresentar propostas que superem algum problema específico.

A idéia é que se um JEP é popular e bem-sucedido, ele será apresentado como parte da próxima especificação formal completa. Essa abordagem possibilita ter JEPs incrementais, ao invés de um grande grupo de mudanças ao mesmo tempo. Esta é a primeira vez que os JEPs foram utilizados e a lista que a Oracle surgiu é relativamente pequena.

**Os JEP propostos para o JDK 9 começam com melhorias na API de processo usada para controlar e gerenciar processos do sistema operacional.** O Java SE oferece suporte limitado para processos do sistema operacional nativo, com uma API básica para configurar o ambiente e iniciar um processo. A sugestão é que isso deve ser estendido para que os desenvolvedores já não tenham que recorrer ao código nativo.

As melhorias para o bloqueio em conflito são a próxima sugestão, com o objetivo de melhorar o desempenho dos monitores de objetos Java contendidos, conforme medido por um conjunto de benchmarks e testes. Isso resultaria em um melhor desempenho em situações em que vários segmentos competem pelo acesso a objetos.
Outro JEP é o fornecimento de um cache de código segmentado que dividirá o código de cache em segmentos distintos, cada um dos quais contém o código compilado de um tipo específico, para melhorar o desempenho e permitir futuras extensões. **Isso seria particularmente aplicável às grandes aplicações.**

O desenvolvimento de uma API JSON leve para consumir e gerar documentos JSON e fluxos de dados também foi sugerido. Isso teria como objetivo atender às necessidades dos desenvolvedores Java usando o JSON.

Uma versão melhor do Smart Java Compiler (sjavac) é outra proposta, Smart Java compilation Phase 2. A ideia é que o sjavac deve ser melhorado para que ele possa ser usado por padrão na compilação JDK e que ele deve ser generalizado para que ele pode ser usado para construir grandes projetos além do JDK.

O JEP final é para código fonte modular. Este é um exercício interno para reorganizar o código-fonte JDK em módulos, aprimorar o sistema de compilação para compilar módulos e impor limites de módulos em tempo de compilação.

A lista completa de JEPs pode ser vista [no site OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/).

Comment: Muito boa a edição! :) +1

Comment: Muito legal, mas o que isso tem a ver com o PHP?

Comment: Thainá, eu particularmente não vi o como isso se aplica ao questionamento do impacto do JDK no NetBeans para desenvolver PHP. Creio que sua resposta seria muito mais on-topic no questionamento da diferença entre Java 8 e Java 9 (que só é abordado de maneira tangencial nessa pergunta)

Comment: Acabei de verificar aqui, a pergunta sobre as diferenças entre o JDK 8 e o 9 não existe no site! Acho que essa é uma ótima oportunidade de postar uma pergunta auto-respondida no SOpt, @ThaináV.

Answer (score 3):

Não, absolutamente nenhuma diferença no desenvolvimento PHP.

Isso porque o JDK ([Java Development Kit](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/pt/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html)) é, como o nome diz, um conjunto de ferramentas que serve para **programar Java**.

O NetBeans é uma IDE que, digamos, tem uma boa relação com o Java, é comum ver programadores Java o usando e até mesmo ler nos blogs da Oracle indicação para baixá-lo.

Por este motivo você deve ter visto alguma coisa falando sobre o NetBeans e o novo JDK, mas isso não interfere na programação de outras linguagens, como no caso do PHP.

Comment: Compreendo, utilizo o Netbeans para desenvolvimento PHP. Mas minha real dúvida (vou melhorar a pergunta no tópico principal) é se o JDK 9 resulta em melhor desempenho do Netbeans (menor consumo de memória, cpu...)?

Comment: Isso mesmo. Utilizo o Netbeans com as extensões e demais complementos do PHP, porém, minha dúvida é referente ao desempenho do Netbeans propriamente dito, isso comparando o uso dele com JDK 8 ou 9.

Answer (score 1):

Netbeans é um IDE completa, porém, pesada, lenta, que consome muito recursos do PC, não da pra escapar disso.

O Netbeans não usa SDK pra ele, ele usa a SDK quando usam dele para programar JAVA.

A versão do JDK que você colocar vai definir o que você vai previamente querer fazer, um exemplo que muda são leves diferenças no perfil da JRE a ser escolhida ( de novo, só muda em projetos JAVA, para o PHP não muda nada).

Talvez o suporte a lambda mude de uma versão pra outra e outras coisas parecidas, mas são mudanças internas, pro programador não vai mudar, e o desempenho do netbeans por si não vai mudar, mas como não programo JAVA não posso afirmar exatamente se muda algo na escrita do projeto.

Ja tem uma resposta boa, não vou aprofundar, mas um observação, o Netbeans é muito completo, mas ele não compensa o uso se vocẽ não usar da maior ferramenta dele que é a personalização, por exemplo, a versão que eu uso é toda alterada, o que até me complica quando preciso/quero atualizar pra uma versão mais recente.

Uma outra observação, o Netbeans com JDK9 não acredito que seja recomendado, pois no próprio site oficial indica que tem suporte apenas, não há documentação oficial sobre seu uso como há para a JDK8 ou anteriores.